# How to select only the latest date for each userId in the data frame, and the list by userId?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

For example, if I want to get only the latest date in the "date" column for each unique userId from the "userId" column (so only the latest date in the data frame for each user, 1:1), and list by userId, how would I go about that in the most efficient way possible? Is there a way to do this?

I'm having a difficult time with this since there are multiple dates listed for each user in the data frame, but I only want the latest date for each user. For example, even if userId 9 had multiple dates from 01/01/2019 to 11/30/2019, and userId 8 had multiple dates in the df from 03/15/2019 to 10/31/2019, is there a way to pull a response such as:

```
 userId Date
   8    10/31/2019
   9    11/30/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "better-than" sql query principal:
You look for something, specifying something that is "better-than" what you're looking for. Then you make sure the "better-than" is null...meaning there isn't anything better than and hence you have the best.

```
select best.userId, best.Date
from theTable as best
left join theTable as better on best.userId = better.userId and better.Date > best.Date
where better.userId is null
group by best.userId;
```

Comment: Why not simply `select id, max(date) from table group by id`?

Comment: because typically I've found when users are trying to perform this sort of action there is never just one field they are trying to prove is better.  it's messy data and usually requires a couple fields to help define what is "bettter"

Comment: Thank you for responding to fast to my question!

Comment: The only issue is that this won't work in Jupyter, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard application of the SQL term `group by`, which slices the data set by each group and applies your desired function (max of date, in this particular case). Pandas is pretty rich in this kind of operations.

So your solution should look like:

```
df.groupby(['UserID'])['Date'].max()
```

Comment: Please share a sample from your dataframe, ie `df.head()` and share the error you are getting.